# Terminal/Application links don't open in browser

Tags: firefox, browser, default-browser

Hi I'm having some trouble on 18.04 LTS where whenever I attempt to open a link within either the terminal or specific applications my Waterfox 2019.10 browser opens up (it's recognized as my default browser in "Preferred Applications") but the link does not load. All it shows is my homepage.
I assume a fix for Firefox would work here as well..

I've tried changing

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser
```

but that didn't seem to help the issue.

edit: so I tried installing waterfox a different way, via the Software desktop utility under waterfox-snap, and now all appears to be working well. Not sure why I had this issue installing from the tar file from waterfox themselves..

Comment: What command are you issuing from the terminal to launch your link?  I don't have any issues running like `firefox www.google.com` or `firefox ~/temp.txt`

Comment: Does `/etc/alternatives/x-www-browser` correctly point to Waterfox? Check with `file /etc/alternatives/x-www-browser`

Comment: Yes the command `file /etc/alternatives/x-www-browser` outputs: `/etc/alternatives/x-www-browser: symbolic link to /opt/waterfox/waterfox`

Answer (score 0):

To open links from the terminal in firefox use `firefox` command :

```
firefox "URL"
```

See `man firefox` for more options.

In general, to open files or links in their default software use the `gio` (Gnome Input/output) utility :

```
gio open "URL"
```

This will open the **URL** in the default browser. If the **URL** is a local file's location, it opens it in its default software.

See `man gio` for more options.

Comment: So when I run the command `gio open "www.speedtest.net"` a new instance of Waterfox opens up but it just goes to my browser startpage, not the requested url. The same is true if I try to click through links in terminal or if a desktop application tries to send me to a link. Just goes to the browser start page not the specific url

Comment: Strangely if I input `/etc/alternatives/x-www-browser www.speedtest.net` it opens up fine but `gio open` doesn't

Comment: @cerpin1taxt Use the full URL with the necessary protocols, in your case `gio open "https://www.speedtest.net"`

Comment: Still doesn't work, same issue. Opens a new browser window but doesn't go to the url

Comment: Is there a way to view/modify what exactly `gio open` is pointing to when it opens a url?

Comment: Are you using Gnome environment cause `gio` only works in Gnome? For KDE, use `kio` or search for the default utility of your desktop environment.

Comment: You can use `gio info "FULL_URL"` to get information about the location. Use manual of gio (`man gio`) for more info.